# Chevy Avalanche grinding/clunking front left side

Tags: chevrolet, grinding, avalanche

Let me start off by saying, I have brought it to my mechanic already and he thought he fixed the problem, but as it turns out the wheel bearing wasn’t the issue. I also want to note I replaced the upper left ball joint.

Here are my symptoms.

After about 2-5 minutes of driving I start to hear a grinding, clunking, noise coming from the front left wheel area. I can feel it in my pedals and my wheel vibrates a little bit.

The noise is inconsistent, but it happens and is most audible at 10-25 mph. I do not hear the noise when I rev the engine at all, only when I’ve been moving for a couple of minutes.

I took a look myself, and noticed my left lower ball joint is slathered in grease and the other is not.

Please help! I’ve spent $680 at the mechanic trying to fix this already and don’t know what to do next.

Comment: Change your mechanic - a significant amount of grease around that ball joint should have been noticed and checked...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a 4x4 or 2wd Avalanche?